# Are methods with a "method could be static" warning considered bad form in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have noticed that if I write a method that only acts on local variables of calling methods (does not directly interact with a class variable) then I get a warning that the method can be static.

Sometimes it's nice to abstract a large piece of code into a separate method. Is this somehow consider bad practice in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Since I keep getting these warnings I'm taking a chance that the post police will pounce on me for asking a question that could invite opinions. Let me defend against that by saying that the warnings I'm getting are not opinions. They are definite warnings. That suggests that there exists an answer that is not opinion, at least from the perspective of the people who decided to create those warnings.

EDIT: 
I was asked to put code here to provide a valid reason as to why I would want to do this. I personally don't think this adds any clarity to question I asked but here's an example of a method that was producing the warning in WebStorm.

```
//Change object array in *.content objects to values array
//noinspection JSMethodCanBeStatic
transformData(visibleData) {
    const ret: any = {};
    ret.headings = visibleData.headings;
    ret.checkbox = this.checkBox;                                                   //add if the table needs checkboxes
    ret.content = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < visibleData.content.length; i++) {
        ret.content.push(_.values(visibleData.content[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The point of this function is to take a clone of the instance, so as not to modify the instance itself, and create a different object, mainly a values only array, which will be used to databind in the template. I did this so my table template could be reusable since columns vary in number.

Comment: Doesn't sound Angular related, only TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the title, content, and tag

Comment: Where do you get those warnings? The compiler itself doesn't produce it, maybe your IDE? Also, it will be helpful if you can show your code.

Comment: Yes. It's the IDE that's warning me. In this case, WebStorm. I can write some code and show you if that will really be helpful but it's exactly what I said. If a method only operates on its caller's local variables then the warning appears. Not sure if other conditions will produce it but that one will.

Comment: Well, if your method doesn't interact with the current state of the instance, then what's the point of it being a method and not a static one? (or even a module function). Maybe you have your reasons, but then please add code to show what it is you're doing.

Comment: There is the code. I don't think it adds any clarity to my question but there it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code which does not interact with instance should be a free function or at least a static method of a class when you believe it is tightly coupled with class API.

Every additional method you add to API has to be supported. So larger classes require more support than smaller classes. In some languages, like Java, you can't have free function, so you have to attach function to some class, but TypeScript and JS are more flexible, so there is no need to pollute class API.

And you could consider it from the performance optimization point of view.

When JS evaluates class method it looks it up in the object instance, than in the object prototype, than in the parent's prototype, etc. Every lookup eats cpu time, so when you think about performance, free function is your choice.

Comment: Interestingly enough, in my example above 'this.checkBox' is an instance variable and its inclusion in the method keeps the IDE from producing the warning. When I comment out that single assignment, I get the warning. Is that assignment preventing the issues you mentioned?

Comment: @ChrisSharp exactly! BTW, did you add it later? Somehow I missed this variable when read your question first.

Comment: I must have added it after suppressing the warning. How does this assignment increase performance? I'm still confused. If that works then why not always bind it to the instance with some arbitrary assignment like that?

Comment: This assignment does not increase performance. Just code analyzer sees that your function has to have access to an instance. Static method can't access instance variables (but yo may passing it as parameter). BTW performance gain is not large. Just in a recent case I had to fight for everything I can squeeze out of app so I mentioned it now :) Just think about making API of the class clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe I now have a tentative grasp on what is happening.